# Node.js error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: node.js, stripe-connect

I am running a Node.js script to get a JSON response from Stripe using these instructions https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#token-request

However, I am getting the following error with the below code:

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

**Code**

```
var app = express();
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request')

app.post('/ptaccountid',(req,res) => {

  var authCode = req.body.code;

  app.post('https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token', {
    form: {
     client_secret: "sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     code: authCode,
     grant_type: "authorization_code",
    }
 }, function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body)
  }
});
});
```

Comment: `app.post` function is not for sending data. `app.post` function is to define a route in the application, its second parameter must be a function which handles a request on that route.

Comment: @juzraai Thanks for this - what structure should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `request.post` instead of `app.post`

Check below code,

```
app.post('/ptaccountid',(req,res) => {
    var authCode = req.body.code;

    request.post('https://connect.stript.com/oauth/token', {
          form: {
           client_secret: "sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
           code: authCode,
           grant_type: "authorization_code",
          }
        }, function(err, response, body) {
          if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I then get the error: `TypeError: req.post is not a function
 `

Comment: My bad!.. It should be `request.post` not `req.post` .. Check my edited post above.

Comment: Welcome @AnnabelleSykes .. Glad that it has been sorted out now! :-)